# How to show Japanese characters in Spyder iPython console?

Tags: character-encoding, console, ipython, spyder, cjk

I am using Conda Spyder GUI via bash on Ubuntu on Windows to access a database that contains Japanese character fields.  At first, when I output that data to the iPython console I could only see boxes as stand-ins for the characters.

Then I installed some additional Japanese fonts, and one of them "mikachan" appeared in the list of rich text fonts and Spyder started using it for Japanese characters in the editor and console.

I installed even more Japanese fonts, and some more of them showed up in the rich text font list, but selecting them has no effect on the font being used in the editor and console.  Even though some are monospace fonts, they do not show up in the list of plain text fonts.

I thought the option to choose which font is used for Japanese characters would be in the Spyder preferences, but it's actually not. (They are being rendered, but not in a font of my choosing.)

How do I change the Japanese character font used in Spyder's iPython console?

(note: Spyder from WinPython on Windows does not have this problem, so it might be something specific to Anaconda or Ubuntu.)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to change that encoding (it's unicode, by the way). Instead, I think you need to convert the text you get from your database to unicode before trying to display it in our consoles.

Comment: The characters were already unicode, but they didn't display until I installed a bunch of Japanese fonts through the Ubuntu terminal.  Sadly, so far only "Mikachan" shows in the console (and it didn't yesterday, and I can't explain what changed), and there is no option to change the font in which the Japanese characters render in the preferences.

Comment: The option is in `Tools > Preferences > General > Appearance > Plain font text`.

Comment: Yeah, it should be, but of the 7 fonts available in that selector none of them are Japanese fonts...not even the one that is actually being used to show the characters (although it does show up in the rich text font list).  The rich text font selector shows a few Japanese fonts, but only a few of the fonts actually installed.

Comment: They have to be monospace fonts to appear there.

Comment: I installed M+ fonts, which include monospace for roman and Japanese characters and should be great for this purpose (https://macwright.org/2014/07/09/mplus.html), but they do not show up as an option for plain text fonts **on this installation**.  Many of the same fonts that appear in my Windows WinPython version do not show up on my Spyder installed on Ubunto on Windows.

Comment: Also, even though I can't select any of the installed Japanese fonts, the console and editor are still using one of the installed Japanese fonts to display Japanese text.  It's just that I can't choose which font Spyder uses, and the one Spyder is using is not a good one for this purpose.